# Dependent Select Box using Jquery and Ajax in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want a dependent select box I can load the data from my database into the select box however, when I click the show all countries when all select boxes have data only the province will return to the default data. What I need to do is when I click show all countries all the data from select box will reset to its default data and so on and so forth.

AJAX Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Show Province
$("#sort-country").change(function(){
    var country = $(this).val();
    $.ajax ({
        url:"fetch_province.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {country:country},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){
            $("#sort-province").html(data);
        }
    });
});

//Show Town
$("#sort-province").change(function(){
    var country = $("#sort-country").val();
    var province = $(this).val();
    $.ajax ({
        url:"fetch_town.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {country:country, province:province},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){
            $("#sort-town").html(data);
        }
    });
});

//Show Barangay
$("#sort-town").change(function(){
    var country = $("#sort-country").val();
    var province = $("#sort-province").val();
    var town = $(this).val();
    $.ajax ({
        url:"fetch_barangay.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {country:country, province:province, town:town},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){
            $("#sort-barangay").html(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Fetch Province:

```
<?php 
require "connect.php";

$output = "";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblLocation WHERE country='".$_POST['country']."' ORDER BY province";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$output = "<option value=''>Show All Province</option>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output .= "<option value='".$row['province']."'>".$row['province']."</option>";
}

echo $output;

?>
```

Fetch Town:

```
<?php 
require "connect.php";

$output = "";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblLocation WHERE country='".$_POST['country']."' AND province='".$_POST['province']."' ORDER BY town";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


$output = "<option value=''>Show All Town</option>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output .= "<option value='".$row['town']."'>".$row['town']."</option>";
}

echo $output;

?>
```

Fetch Barangay:

```
<?php 
require "connect.php";

$output = "";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblLocation WHERE country='".$_POST['country']."' AND province='".$_POST['province']."' AND town='".$_POST['town']."' ORDER BY barangay";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$output = "<option value=''>Show All Barangay</option>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output .= "<option value='".$row['barangay']."'>".$row['barangay']."</option>";
}

echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: call change event of the third select in the first select like `$("#sort-town").change();` after `$("#sort-province").html(data);`

Comment: Oh I get it now thank you!

Comment: did it work now? grad to help mate happy coding :)

Comment: yes it work the problem now is to echo the markers in my google map when sorting